# layout 4 images 50% width and height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to create a layout for my Android app in which I want to Show Images, each Images shall have a width of 50% and a height of 50%, how can I achieve this so far I built following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="test.com.tests.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableRow>
            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/tbl_txt1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Column 1"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/tbl_txt2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Column 2"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Something like this:
https://ibb.co/c2Gngc

Comment: Post an expected output image.

Comment: @Abhi something like this my paint skills suck https://ibb.co/c2Gngc

Answer (score 0):

You use something like this If you want to use TableLayout only

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_weight="1">

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to dynamically add data to that view later on, would I always Needs to generaet a relativelayout with a linear and then the imageviews?

Comment: You need to be more clear with your post title, you have mentioned that you need 4 images with 50%

Comment: if there are only 4 items you can use this to dynamically populate items, else try `recyclerview/gridview`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```